# Adding two rows together in pandas to make a long row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hopefully a quick question, but I have two DataFrames from which I have pulled one row out of each, based on the name I'm looking for:

```
mmb_df[mmb_df['name'] == mmb_name]

jps_df[jps_df['name'] == jps_name]
```

This gives me two rows of about 60 columns each, and I all I want to do is to combine them so I have one 1 row of 120 columns. Some of the columns do have the same name but I'm not sure if that makes any difference.

If I had two rows such as this:

```
name     tag   x    y 
001_Dc   F     243  567

name     tag   position1    position2
jps_043  EW    908          219
```

I just need them as this:

```
name     tag   x    y     name      tag   position1   position2
001_Dc   F     243  567   jps_043   EW    908         219
```

I'm sure this can be done easily but I've had no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need same indices first and then use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

Here use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) is not good solution, because not avoid duplicate columns names.

```
pd.concat([a,b], axis=1)
```

---

```
a = mmb_df[mmb_df['name'] == mmb_name]
b = jps_df[jps_df['name'] == jps_name]

#same both indices
b.index = a.index

#or implicitely set indices
#a.index = [0] 
#b.index = [0] 
c = a.join(b, lsuffix='first')
```

If is possible some condition return more rows is possible select first only:

```
a = a.iloc[[0]]
b = b.iloc[[0]]
b.index = a.index
c = a.join(b, lsuffix='first')
```

Or set first indices to `0` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with double `[]`:

```
a = a.iloc[[0]].set_index([[0]])
b = b.iloc[[0]].set_index([[0]])
c = a.join(b, lsuffix='first')
```

Solution for first rows only - get first `True` row by [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) and select by `loc`:

```
a = mmb_df.loc[[(mmb_df['name'] == mmb_name).idxmax()]].set_index([[0]])
b = jps_df.loc[[(jps_df['name'] == jps_name).idxmax()]].set_index([[0]])

c = a.join(b, lsuffix='first')
```

Comment: Thank you, that first solution worked, had to add a suffix argument to the join function for the columns with the same names.

Answer (score 3):

Pandas [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) could also works:

```
df1.index = df2.index
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner',  left_index=True, right_index=True, sort=True, suffixes=('_x', '_y'))
```

output :

```
    name_x  tag_x   x   y   name_y  tag_y   position1   position2
0   001_Dc  F   243 567 jps_043 EW  908 219
```